# solution to equations having 4 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I have the following set of equations:

$$
\frac{x^2}{2^2-1} + \frac{y^2}{2^2 - 3^2} + \frac{z^2}{2^2-5^2} + \frac{w^2}{2^2-7^2} = 1
$$

$$
\frac{x^2}{4^2-1} + \frac{y^2}{4^2 - 3^2} + \frac{z^2}{4^2-5^2} + \frac{w^2}{4^2-7^2} = 1
$$
$$
\frac{x^2}{6^2-1} + \frac{y^2}{6^2 - 3^2} + \frac{z^2}{6^2-5^2} + \frac{w^2}{6^2-7^2} = 1
$$
$$
\frac{x^2}{8^2-1} + \frac{y^2}{8^2 - 3^2} + \frac{z^2}{8^2-5^2} + \frac{w^2}{8^2-7^2} = 1
$$

Well the nature of numbers in the denominator itself freaked me out and now I am unable to approach the question. I tried to simplify the expressions which turned out to be of no use. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just write it in matrix form $Au=b$, where $u = (x^2, y^2,z^2, w^2) ^T$and invert the matrix, that will give you the values of the squares.

Comment: From where does it come?

Comment: ${{x}^{2}}=\frac{11025}{1024},{{y}^{2}}=\frac{10395}{1024},{{z}^{2}}=\frac{9009}{1024}and\ {{w}^{2}}=\frac{6435}{1024}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many methods but i prefer to use matrix

Then i try to solve the system
$AX=T $, where

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1}{2^2-1} & \frac{1}{2^2-3^2} & \frac{1}{2^2-5^2} & \frac{1}{2^2-7^2} \\
 \frac{1}{4^2-1} & \frac{1}{4^2-3^2} & \frac{1}{4^2-5^2} & \frac{1}{4^2-7^2} \\
 \frac{1}{6^2-1} & \frac{1}{6^2-3^2} & \frac{1}{6^2-5^2} & \frac{1}{6^2-7^2} \\
 \frac{1}{8^2-1} & \frac{1}{8^2-3^2} & \frac{1}{8^2-5^2} & \frac{1}{8^2-7^2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and

$$X=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x^2 \\
 y^2 \\
 z^2 \\
 w^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and

$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

to find $X$ we must calculate the inverse matrix of $A$  and then multuply by the $T$ we can get

$$X=\frac{1}{1024}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 11025 \\
 10395 \\
 9009 \\
 6435 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

finally

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
 z \\
 w \\
\end{array}
\right)=\pm\sqrt{X}=\pm\frac{1}{32}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 105 \\
 3 \sqrt{1155} \\
 3 \sqrt{1001} \\
 3 \sqrt{715} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

i used a Math Software

Comment: Don't forget to sprinkle liberally with $\pm$s, to get the full $16$ possible solutions. :-)

Comment: verification : $\frac{10395}{2^2-3^2}+\frac{9009}{2^2-5^2}+\frac{6435}{2^2-7^2}+\frac{11025}{2^2-1}$ you get 1024

Comment: thanks for the solution but is there a way to solve it by not making use of the huge numbers

Comment: maybe there are a pretty method but sorry i have not  time for think in it .